# Проблема с foreignKey

Tags: python, django

помогите пожалуйста извлечь и вывести данные при помощи foreignKey

[models.py:](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/fk.jpg)

```
class Gender(models.Model):     
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, 
        blank=False,
    )

class UserProfile(User):
    name1 = models.CharField(
        'Имя',
        max_length=30, 
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    gender = models.ForeignKey(
        Gender,
        default=0,
    )
```

fixtures:

```
[
    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Gender",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "gender": "none"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Gender",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "gender": "male"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Gender",
        "pk": 3,
        "fields": {
        "gender": "female"
        }
    }   
]
```

views.py:

```
def user_personal(request, id):     
    entries_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_ptr_id=id)

    t = loader.get_template('user_personal.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'entries_user_profile': entries_user_profile,
    })  
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

user_personal.html:

```
{% if entries_user_profile.gender_id %}
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Пол</td>

        <td class="gender info">{{ entries_user_profile.gender_id }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
```

проблема в том, что не выводится значение gender из таблицы Gender(none, male or female)

ps
пробовал выводить так: `<td class="gender info">{{ entries_user_profile.gender.gender }}</td>`
выводится пустое значение

pps
пожалуйста не предлагайте использовать CHOICES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ entries_user_profile.gender.gender }}
```

Это правильно. Видимо ничего там просто нет. Юзеру точно задан пол? Потому как по дефолту присваивается `0`, а в БД записи с `id=0` нет…

Comment: натюрлихь! )) всё действительно так)

Comment: Запись 'none' в модель делать не очень правильно. Нет у вас данных - пусть там и будет None, а не ForeignKey на "типа пустой" объект